# Why does this variable have no value even though it is set in .bashrc?

Tags: bash, environment-variables, quoting

If I append this:

```
hi=11
export hi
```

to the .bashrc and then I su to this user with:

```
su - bela
```

then I:

```
echo $hi
11
```

Then it's working, the "hi" variable has the value of "11". But. When I:

```
su -c "echo $hi" bela
```

the variable "hi" has no value. Why?

(running on CentOS 6)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`su -c "echo $hi" bela` expands to the words `su`, `-c`, `echo ​` and `bela`. Since the variable `hi` is not defined in your current shell, its expansion is empty. The command that is executed as user `bela` is `echo ​`.

Fix: `su -c 'echo $hi' bela`, with the single quotes protecting the `$` from expansion… Not. The `.bashrc` file is only read by interactive shells. When you run `su -c 'echo $hi' bela`, this executes `echo $hi` as user `bela`. But since nothing is defining the variable `hi`, the command `echo $hi` expands to `echo` which still prints nothing.

Comment: yeah, interesting.  i would have expected a non-login shell opened by `su` to read .bashrc, but it doesn't.  moving the definition of `$hi` to .bash_profile works when used with `su -c 'echo $hi' -l bela`, though, when the login shell reads `.bash_profile`.

Comment: it works with ' ' :D